# Selectize.js with Tags, Reload selected keys and values on edit form

Tags: javascript, selectize.js

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC Application using Selectize.js in my search (`action=GET`) form. One of the inputs uses Selectize as follows:

```
        $("#selectize").each(function () {
            $(this).selectize({
                plugins: ['remove_button'],
                valueField: 'Acronym',
                labelField: 'Name',
                searchField: ['Acronym', 'Name'],
                create: false,
                persist: false,
                preload: true,
                initUrl: "/Attorneys/GetAllJson/",
                initData: true,
                load: function (query, callback) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Attorneys/GetAllJson/",
                        type: 'GET',
                        error: function () {
                            callback();
                        },
                        success: function (res) {
                            callback(res);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Everything if ok when the form is empty. The option shows the acronym and the name of the attorney perfectly in the Selectize input. Submitting the form, the input sends the values correctly separated by commas, as expected.

When I perform a search, the form is filled correctly with the values I've previously selected in the previous screen, but the attorney's names don't appear with the respective acronyms.

Listing the available options, all the other attorneys are showed correctly. The selected attorneys appear only as the acronyms.

I tried [this](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/issues/522) (I don't use `data-data`: I use the value from `input`) and [the solutions from this](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/issues/366) (didn't work).

Is there a way to reload these selected options with the proper remote values?